# Adding map_view to my flutter app is not successful

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, flutter

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'android' is using version 1.1.2-4.

The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.1.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.1.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

Comment: How do I use map_view with the latest version of flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Due to this package not being an "official" package made by the development team I fear it might be a problem from the developer's side. I saw that an issue was made in the related repository https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/140 Try to see if there's an answer there.

---

If you want an alternative answer I'd recommend the following:

- [flutter_map](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map) is a great package which is used for Dart implementation of Leaflet for Flutter apps. Basically, you can use OpenStreetMap (free) to get map views, markers and so much more.
- [flutter_native_map](https://github.com/xclud/flutter_native_map) doesn't look like you need a google maps key nor any specific set-up. Check it out.

Both support iOS and Android.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to your flutter sdk repository on your disk, go to for example `<flutter_dir>.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\map_view-0.0.14\android` and change `ext.kotlin_version` according with the same on your `build.gradle` project.

This fix could be reproduced for all plugins that have their kotlin version in conflict with your app because your can found all the other plugins in the folder of the previous path called `pub.dartlang.org`.